# rails-3jquery-automcomplete path helper not returning correct path in rails 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I have a model:

```
class EvidenceType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :evidences

  attr_accessible :name

end
```

A controller:

```
class EvidencesController < ApplicationController

  autocomplete :evidence_type, :name
```

In my view:

```
<%= form_tag do %>            
    <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'evidence', '', :autocomplete => autocomplete_evidence_type_name_evidences_path %>
<% end %>
```

In Routes.rb:

```
resources :evidences do
  get :autocomplete_evidence_type_name, :on => :collection
end
```

rake routes gives me:

```
autocomplete_evidence_type_name_evidences GET    /evidences/autocomplete_evidence_type_name(.:format) {:action=>"autocomplete_evidence_type_name", :controller=>"evidences"}
```

When i start typing in the autocomplete field i see a request int the rails log:

```
Started GET "/autocomplete/evidences/autocomplete_evidence_type_name?term=co" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Oct 11 17:45:57 +0100 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/autocomplete/evidences/autocomplete_evidence_type_name"):
```

If I manually go to http://localhost:3000/evidences/autocomplete_evidence_type_name?term=xx then i get the desired snippet returned, which leads me to believe everything seems to be glued together properly with jquery.

I figure I either need to add an extra 'autocomplete' to my route (seems hackish?) or that my autocomplete_evidence_type_name_evidences_path helper needs to drop the /autocomplete off of the front.

However, having said this, I suspect that it might be me that is doing something wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'evidence', '', :autocomplete => autocomplete_evidence_type_name_evidences_path %>
```

You don't need `:autocomplete =>`. That is what's adding the extra `/autocomplete` to the URL. Just use:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'evidence', '', autocomplete_evidence_type_name_evidences_path %>
```

I used this gem for a while and unless something has changed in the past few months, that should fix it for you.

Comment: brilliant, thanks! got myself in trouble with cut and paste :)